# Integrateing Web Aplication into users websites

Tags: web-applications, web

So guys I need an advice, pointers, anything....

We are working on a web application that is suppose to be integrated into our clients website.
App would run on our local servers, and it's written in Microsoft Visual Studio.
First of all we thought that we put it in  and our users can integrate it into their websites, and eventually edit it so it fits their design better, and we found out about Same Origin Policy so we discarded that option...

So I'd appreciate any advice or pointers on where to look next to "fix" this problem, and with what tools to do this...

Answer (score 0):

If you can live with not supporting all browsers out there (i.e. for intra- and extranets), check out [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) ([more](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/xhr.html)).

If your client can point a subdomain to your server (ie. yourapp.yourclient.com or yourapp.www.yourclient.nl) you wouldn't have the problem, so I'd check that out too.

Otherwise the easiest way of 'fixing' this would be to have a proxy application running on the customer's servers. Each call to that application would translate 1-to-1 to a call to yours. This can get hairy when you need to log in a user, to show personal information.

You could also check out JSONP.